# Where does $H = \frac{M_0}{T^2}$ come from?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, temperature, space-expansion, big-bang

In this case: $M_0 = \frac{M_{Pl}}{1.66 g_*^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and $H$ is the Hubble constant (which is not always constant depending on he constitution of the Universe).

where $M_{Pl}$ is Planck's mass and $g_*$ the effective number of relativistic degrees of freedom.

I noticed this relationship several times in my textbook, especially in decoupling relationships (such as the decoupling of photons, neutrons, etc.) where $H$
(as a function of T) is compared to the reaction rate $\sigma n v$ (as a function of T). Then it is used to find an expression for T.

Where does $H = \frac{M_0}{T^2}$ come from?

Additionally, how can you equate H a constant with a reaction rate? Does this come from mean free path and collisions?

Comment: Consider defining your symbols and the context in which they appear.

Comment: A textbook on what subject?

Comment: @J. Murray I defined the symbols from the first equation. Is there something still missing?

Comment: @mikestone The textbook is about cosmology.

Comment: Um, no you did not define the symbols.  Your original post had only   "Where does $=_/t^2$ come from?"  Do not rewrite history!

Comment: What do you mean "Your original post had only "Where does H=M/t2 come from?""? It is written in the description. I did not make an empty post.

Comment: I forgot to write that H is the Hubble constant (which is not always a constant depending on the composition of the Universe).

Comment: @Maj Is $T$ a temperature?